# Cast as decimal of left character to use with less than logic

Tags: mysql

I have a table `table1` with columns `stringvar1` and `stringvar2`. The `stringvar2` entries all begin with numbers, followed by spaces and letters and sometimes other numbers. I'm attempting to select where this first character in the string is less than 8 when considered as a number.

This is what I've tried.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE
( stringvar1 LIKE '%33 knicker%' or var1 LIKE '%34 knicker%')
and 
(  cast(left (stringvar2,1) as decimal (1,1)) < 8 )
```

This is generating a syntax error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'decimal (1,1)) < 8
>
> ) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
where left(stringvar, 1) between '0' and '7'
```

or, even more simply:

```
where stringvar >= '0' and stringval < '8'
```

If you really want to use `cast()` then cast to `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: Perfect. I was making it more difficult than it needed to be. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
cast(left (stringvar2,1) as decimal (1,1))
```

Parenthesis problem.

```
cast(left (stringvar2,1)) as decimal (1,1)
```